# How to parse DSL file to HTML?

Tags: java, parsing, syntax, trees

There's [DSL](http://jalingo.sourceforge.net/dictionaries/) format for creating and distributing dictionaries. Every dictionary article in such formats looks like this:

```
algorithm
    [m0][b]al·go·rithm[/b] {{id=000001018}} [c rosybrown]\[[/c][c darkslategray][b]algorithm[/b][/c] [c darkslategray][b]algorithms[/b][/c][c rosybrown]\][/c] [p]BrE[/p] [c darkgray] [/c][c darkcyan]\[ˈælɡərɪðəm\][/c] [s]z_algorithm__gb_1.wav[/s] [p]NAmE[/p] [c darkgray] [/c][c darkcyan]\[ˈælɡərɪðəm\][/c] [s]z_algorithm__us_1.wav[/s] [c orange] noun[/c] [c darkgray] ([/c][c green]computing[/c][c darkgray])[/c]
    [m1]{{d}}a set of rules that must be followed when solving a particular problem{{/d}} [m3] 
    {{Word Origin}}[m3][c darkslategray][u]Word Origin:[/u][/c]
    [m3][c darkgray] [/c]{{d}}late 17th cent.{{/d}} [c dimgray]{{etymology}} (denoting the Arabic or decimal notation of numbers): variant (influenced by {{/etymology}} [/c][c darkslategray]{{lang}}Greek{{/lang}} [/c][c darkgray] [/c][c darkcyan]{{ff}}arithmos{{/ff}} [/c][c darkgray] [/c][c darkslateblue][b]{{etym_tr}}‘number’{{/etym_tr}}[/b][/c][c dimgray]{{etymology}}) of {{/etymology}} [/c][c darkslategray]{{lang}}Middle English{{/lang}} [/c][c darkgray] [/c][c darkslategray]{{etym_i}}algorism{{/etym_i}}[/c][c dimgray]{{etymology}}, via {{/etymology}} [/c][c darkslategray]{{lang}}Old French{{/lang}} [/c][c dimgray]{{etymology}} from {{/etymology}} [/c][c darkslategray]{{lang}}medieval Latin{{/lang}} [/c][c darkgray] [/c][c darkcyan]{{ff}}algorismus{{/ff}}[/c][c dimgray]{{etymology}}. The {{/etymology}} [/c][c darkslategray]{{lang}}Arabic{{/lang}} [/c][c dimgray]{{etymology}} source, {{/etymology}} [/c][c darkcyan]{{ff}}al-K̲wārizmī{{/ff}} [/c][c darkgray] [/c][c darkslateblue][b]{{etym_tr}}‘the man of K̲wārizm’{{/etym_tr}} [/b][/c][c dimgray]{{etymology}} (now Khiva), was a name given to the 9th-cent. mathematician Abū Ja‘far Muhammad ibn Mūsa, author of widely translated works on algebra and arithmetic.{{/etymology}} [/c]
```

I need to parse it to **HTML** in **Java** application.
My question is how to do it? I have thought about two options,

- write multiple `regex` expressions which will cover all cases
- parse it to something like a semantic tree by dividing to nodes, and each node parse on its own

Absolutely have no experience with such kind of task, so I asking for advice and possible pitfalls.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an actual specification for the DSL rather than just some examples?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find an official spec but find an old document where someone reverse engineered it. I didn't mention it here because of it in the Russian language. I have converted it from *.chm file and placed here if you wish give it a look ;) https://anatoly314.github.io/dsl-manual/

Comment: Google search suggests this DSL may be from a product called ABBYY Lingvo, and that company documents the DSL but that some users considered the docs incomplete and built a separate guide. See https://lingvoboard.ru/forum/ and https://www.lingvolive.com

Comment: This *separate guide* is the same guide I referenced to.

Comment: @Anatoly Understood. I posted the links because I thought you might not know it came from ABBYY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a bunch of regex expressions and then write a bunch of code that will figure out when which regex should be used.  This is actually not a terrible idea for something fairly simple.  For something like this, you probably want define a [grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) and use a tool like [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) to build a lexer/parser.

It can be a little intimidating at first but there are lots of resources that can help.  I would try one of the tutorials and build a simple language parser first.  You should find a lot of overlap with regular expressions and the way you use them.

Answer (score 1):

**Why not convert it to a form where existing tools can parse it?**

This DSL looks like it could easily be converted to XML.

There appear to be four types of 'Elements' in the example.

- Elements that follow the pattern [tag-name]*[/tag-name]
- Elements that follow the pattern {{tag-name}}*{{/tag-name}}
- Self-closing Elements that have the pattern {{tag-name=value-string}}
- A free-standing text element with no surrounding tags

**Speculation:** It appears the two types of elements are not expected to be interleaved, e.g.

- [x]{{y}}blah [/x] blah{{/y}}

**How about a cheap to code conversion to XML?**

If this is correct you could decide how you would like each of these patterns converted to XML elements. For example:

- Convert "[tag-name]" to `<tag-name>` and "[/tag-name]" to `</tag-name>`
- Convert "{{tag-name}}" and "{{/tag-name}}" to `<cc-tag-name>` and `</cc-tag-name>`
- Convert "{{tag-name=value-string}}" to `<tag-name>value</tag-name>` or `<tag-name value=value-string/>` for example
- Leave free-standing text nodes as-is. XML (and HTML) supports those already.

You could do this conversion using global replace with three regex. You could do it with a hand-coded recursive parser-converter (that would be pretty small).

Although most people would probably prefer regex for this job, I would tend to write the hand coded converter in this case because I would like to put some structure validation into the process, e.g. to log or handle the case where elements are interleaved in a way XML will not support.

I would like to find out early on whether the source data violates my assumptions.

**You need to know the valid character set and escaping rules.**

If you have a large volume of input data to read, you are likely to encounter odd cases, such as unfamiliar unicode characters that may need normalizing, or may be expressed in some form of "entity" notation in the data.

At the very least you need to know how [, ], {{, }}, / are escaped when they occur in text and are not part of markup. If you don't handle this there's a good chance your process will fail on some dictionary entries.

The documentation might tell you these things. It's worth a look.

**OK Great. We have XML but we wanted HTML**

The point of converting into XML is that you are then free to use the many free open-source tools for parsing XML, transforming XML, deserializing XML into Objects of your design.

When you generate HTML you will make a lot of decisions that are not included in this input data.

- Navigation: How will users navigate to different entries? Will entries always display in full detail, or will there also be a short form?
- Formatting, presentation: Mapping this markup into your html structure and css style sheets. Some sections of the input look like they might want margins/indenting that are not included in the markup.
- Search: For decent user experience you may need to also extract indexing terms from this markup and load them to a text search service.
- Accessibility: if that's part of your requirements.
- Images? If there are any, they may need preprocessing.

You may want parse it into POJO's (e.g. with Jackson or other reflection based deserializer) and use html templates (e.g. Freemarker, Thymeleaf, Velocity, even JSP). You'll probably want css styles separate from the main text of the documents if only for flexibility to change presentation without reprocessing all data.

Putting the data in XML or some other well-supported format lets you choose from  many tools for these more complex tasks.

But it is not necessary, and if you don't think it would save you time you probably should not do it.

You can, of course, parse the input directly into your chosen Java object model or directly into HTML. ANTLR is great but as previous answer suggests there is a significant setup and learning curve.

Comment: As an aside, if you've used ANTLR2 or prior in the past but not ANTLR3, the author had an epiphany and greatly simplified the design to better meet the needs of developers.  As such it's much less difficult to learn and use.

Comment: I think actually I mean ANTLR4 vs 3, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a live example how it can converted into HTML in simple and dirty way in the project [ebview dictionary viewer application](https://github.com/eb4j/ebviewer/blob/main/src/main/java/io/github/eb4j/ebview/dictionary/lingvo/LingvoDSLDictionary.java)

You can find a manual of tags at [ABBYY lingvo site](http://lingvo.helpmax.net/en/troubleshooting/dsl-compiler/dsl-tags/)

There is an idea that it uses regex replacement between DSL tags and HTML tags. For example, we can replace `[b]...[/b]` into `<span font-style="bold">...</span>`. There are several rules of replacements. Because the example ignores some tags, please take care that it may not be fit to your requirements.

A manual don't say about

```
 {{brah}}
```

style of tags, I cannot say about it.

You can do it with following code;

```
static class LingvoDSLTag {
    private static final List<RE> RE_LIST;

    static String replaceTag(final String line) {
        String result = line;
        for (RE re : RE_LIST) {
            result = re.pattern.matcher(result).replaceAll(re.replacement);
        }
        return result;
    }

    static {
        List<RE> reList = new ArrayList<>();
        reList.add(new RE("\\[\\[(.+?)\\]\\]", "&#91;$1&#93;"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\\\\\[", "&#91;"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\\\\\]", "&#93;"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[b\\](.+?)\\[/b\\]", "<strong>$1</strong>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[i\\](.+?)\\[/i\\]", "<span style='font-style: italic'>$1</span>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[trn\\](.+?)\\[/trn\\]", "$1"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[t\\](.+?)\\[/t\\]", "$1&nbsp;"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[br\\]", "<br/>"));
        // Green is default color in Lingvo
        reList.add(new RE("\\[c\\](.+?)\\[/c\\]", "<span style='color:green'>$1</span>"));
        // The following line tries to replace [c value]text[/c] with text colored as per the value.
        // Since the color names are plain words like 'red', or 'blue', or 'steelgray' etc.,
        reList.add(new RE("\\[c\\s([a-z]+?)\\](.+?)\\[/c\\]", "<span style='color:$1'>$2</span>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[com\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/com\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[ex\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/ex\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[lang\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/lang\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "$1"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m1\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 30px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m2\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 60px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m3\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 90px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m4\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 90px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m5\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 90px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m6\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 90px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m7\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 90px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m8\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 90px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[m9\\](.+?)\\[/m\\]", "<p style=\"text-indent: 90px\">$1</p>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[p\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/p\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[preview\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/preview\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[ref\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/ref\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[s\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/s\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[sub\\](.+?)\\[/sub\\]", "<sub>$1</sub>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[sup\\](.+?)\\[/sup\\]", "<sup>$1</sup>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[trn1\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/trn1\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[trs\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/trs\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[\\!trs\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/\\!trs\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[u\\](.+?)\\[/u\\]",
                "<span style='text-decoration:underline'>$1</span>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[url\\](.+?)\\[/url\\]", "<a href='$1'>$1</a>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[video\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/video\\]", ""));
        // The following line tries to replace a letter surrounded by ['][/'] tags (indicating stress)
        // with a red letter (the default behavior in Lingvo).
        reList.add(new RE("\\['\\].\\[/'\\]", "<span style='color:red'>$1</span>"));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[\\*\\]", ""));
        reList.add(new RE("\\[/\\*\\]", ""));
        RE_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(reList);
    }
}
```

This would be a good start point to build your code.

The example project is licensed under GPLv3. I'd like to license the chunk above as CC-BY-SA 4.0.